# How can hping be so fast to send packets?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, raw-sockets, packet-injection

I have compared two tools for the speed of sending packets, `hping` and `packETHcli`. The command line options for packETHcli is

```
./packETHcli -i eth0 -m 2 -n 0 -d -1 -f icmpSample.pcap
```

and for hping is

```
hping --flood 192.168.0.1
```

But in iptraf, it shows that the packets sending speed of hping is about 10 times faster than packETHcli.

Both tools use raw sockets, but why such a big difference?

Here is the link to get the source codes.

hping: http://wiki.hping.org/

packETHcli: http://sourceforge.net/projects/packeth/

**EDIT:**
 I noticed that the `hping` use AF_INET raw socket, the payload is TCP. `packETHcli` use PF_PACKET raw socket, and in my example the payload is and IP packet with payload of ICMP.
Do it make the difference of the packet sending speed ?

**EDIT2**

This time,I use ifconfig to find the TX packets count difference between before and after running `hping3` and `packETHcli`.  And found that the packets generating rates are close for the two tools. `hping3` is about 100000 packets per seconds and `packETHcli` is about 80000 packets per seconds.

I also use `vnstat` to measure the packets generating rates. And the result is consistent with the number I get from `ifconfig`.

So, it seems that `iptraf` lies. And I use `iptraf` to monitor the repeated resending of a TCP packet, without update the IP ID number and TCP sequence number. `iptraf` think my packet sending rate is 0 packets per seconds. May be `iptraf` don't count the duplicated packets?

Comment: Are they both maxing out on CPU usage? Perhaps one is more efficiently coded than the other. (As a specialized tool, hping is probably leaner).

Comment: @nneonneo They both use sendto() to send the raw packet, and wrapped in a for(;;) or while(1) loop. Both run in single thread.

Comment: Mhm, but how much other crud is there in that loop? All I'm asking is to do a `top` comparison of CPU usage to see if they are both maxing out the CPU. You may also want to see if they are maxing out the network with `ntop`.

Comment: @nneonneo The CPU utilization of `packETHcli` is about 19% and `hping3` is 100%. `hping3` build the packet manually in userspace, then send it through sendto(2) and it repeats this process in each loop of while(1). And `packETHcli` just call sendto(2) with same packet data in the loop of for(;;), the packet data is read from icmpSample.pcap file at program startup once, not repeats in the loop.

Comment: So that must mean that `packETHcli` is blocking a lot. I wonder if `hping3` uses any non-blocking options for the socket. (You may use `strace` if you want to know exactly how the sockets are being configured).

Comment: In the example `packETHcli` reads a .pcap from the disk. No wonder it is slower than generating data in memory. It also explains the blocking.

Comment: @thuovila It is not the problem, it only read the packet data once, and use it in the loop repeatedly. So it's not blocked on the disk I/O.

Comment: @nneonneo ,@thuovila, Thanks for your advice. I updated my question, added my latest testing result. And I think I found the answer. Let me know your comments.

Answer (score 0):

There is timestamp information for each packet in the *.pcap file. And I think the tool packETHcli is parsing the *.pcap file, using the timestamp information to simulate the network environment where the *.pcap file is captured, that means it has to add some delay between packets according to the timestamp.

While hping does not.

I think that's the difference.

If so, is there any option in the packETHcli tool which supports to speed up the packets sending?